# Adding 2 Values together in JS

Tags: javascript

So this probably pretty simple to do, but I'm now just learning this. I'm trying to add two values together to fill an input

Obviously that doesn't work, can someone please lend a hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `;` between the 2 values you are adding remove it like:

```
var summedValues = userInfo.fname + userInfo.lname;
```

In javascript `;` means the end of the line and therefore it is not taking the consideration the `+` that is after it.

Comment: Thanks, how do I got about adding a space in there?

Comment: @KevinFong Like this `userInfo.fname + ' ' + userInfo.lname;`